# docker how to break COPY into multiple lines

Tags: docker

The Dockerfile causes the error.

> Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 4: COPY requires at least two arguments, but only one was provided. Destination could not be determined.

Is it because COPY command cannot split into multiple lines? What is the way to split into multiple lines then? There are examples for `RUN` command using `\ &&` but not sure of `COPY`.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
WORKDIR /app

COPY [
    "requirements.txt",
    "serving/main.py",
    "."
]
RUN pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["/app/main.py"]
```

I can put into one line but it is not readable.

```
COPY [ "requirements.txt", "serving/main.py", "training/simple_linear_regr_utils.py", "training/simple_linear_regr.py", "."]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Docker COPY commands be chained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643508/can-docker-copy-commands-be-chained)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a `Dockerfile`, `\` is the line continuation character. It can be used to split *any* directive across multiple physical lines. `&&` has nothing to do with `Dockerfile` syntax; that's shell syntax is only relevant in `RUN` lines (which are executed by the shell).

So you can write:

```
COPY requirements.txt \
     serving/main.py \
     .
```

But! That probably won't do what you want, in that you'll end up with a directory that looks like:

```
/app
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

That is, it copies everything into the same directory without preserving the directory hierarchy (but so does your `COPY [ ... ]` version).

Comment: Being a little pedantic: `\` is the default escape character. When it precedes a newline, it is considered a line continuation.

Comment: Did you mean ` \ `? For some reason backslashes in comments behave differently than backslashes in question/answer content.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant! I forgot backslashes are weird in comments.